# API JSON Data not showing correct on Flutter Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm trying to display football scores on an application. I'm able to display the correct scores for some teams or games, but other scores are not displaying the right data. I know the reason for this has to do with the structure of the scores in the JSON array. Can anyone point me to the right direction to display the scores?

Scores Structure in Nested JSON

```
"scores": [
                {
                    "id": 13080434,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 2,
                    "participant_id": 1028,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 3,
                        "participant": "away"
                    },
                    "description": "2ND_HALF"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13079819,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 1525,
                    "participant_id": 581,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 1,
                        "participant": "home"
                    },
                    "description": "CURRENT"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13079768,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 1,
                    "participant_id": 1028,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 2,
                        "participant": "away"
                    },
                    "description": "1ST_HALF"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13079820,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 1525,
                    "participant_id": 1028,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 3,
                        "participant": "away"
                    },
                    "description": "CURRENT"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13079767,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 1,
                    "participant_id": 581,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 1,
                        "participant": "home"
                    },
                    "description": "1ST_HALF"
                },
                {
                    "id": 13080433,
                    "fixture_id": 18860495,
                    "type_id": 2,
                    "participant_id": 581,
                    "score": {
                        "goals": 1,
                        "participant": "home"
                    },
                    "description": "2ND_HALF"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Full Json response from API

```
[

    {
        "id": 18841640,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 8,
        "season_id": 21646,
        "stage_id": 77464011,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 307067,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 200,
        "name": "Burnley vs Aston Villa",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 13:00:00",
        "result_info": "Aston Villa won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693141200,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13080393,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 15,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13080394,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 27,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079799,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 15,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079800,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 27,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079813,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 15,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079814,
                "fixture_id": 18841640,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 27,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18841645,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 8,
        "season_id": 21646,
        "stage_id": 77464011,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 307067,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 2,
        "name": "Sheffield United vs Manchester City",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 13:00:00",
        "result_info": "Manchester City won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693141200,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13080469,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 9,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13080470,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 21,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079837,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 9,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079874,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 9,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079838,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 21,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13079873,
                "fixture_id": 18841645,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 21,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18841644,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 8,
        "season_id": 21646,
        "stage_id": 77464011,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 307067,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 449,
        "name": "Newcastle United vs Liverpool",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 15:30:00",
        "result_info": "Liverpool won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693150200,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13082498,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 20,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082497,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 8,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081839,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 8,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081837,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 8,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081838,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 20,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081840,
                "fixture_id": 18841644,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 20,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18847951,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 564,
        "season_id": 21694,
        "stage_id": 77464219,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 307676,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": null,
        "name": "Villarreal vs FC Barcelona",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 15:30:00",
        "result_info": "FC Barcelona won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693150200,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13082513,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 3477,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082514,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 83,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 4,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081845,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 3477,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081846,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 83,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 4,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081833,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 3477,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081834,
                "fixture_id": 18847951,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 83,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18863199,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 82,
        "season_id": 21795,
        "stage_id": 77464501,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 309273,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 53,
        "name": "FC Bayern München vs FC Augsburg",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 15:30:00",
        "result_info": "FC Bayern München won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693150200,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13082485,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 503,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082486,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 90,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081841,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 503,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 3,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081835,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 503,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081836,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 90,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13081842,
                "fixture_id": 18863199,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 90,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "id": 18867323,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 384,
        "season_id": 21818,
        "stage_id": 77464586,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 309695,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 118500,
        "name": "Juventus vs Bologna",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 16:30:00",
        "result_info": "Game ended in draw.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693153800,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13082553,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 625,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082554,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 8513,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082557,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 625,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082558,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 8513,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082951,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 625,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13082952,
                "fixture_id": 18867323,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 8513,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18867324,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 384,
        "season_id": 21818,
        "stage_id": 77464586,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 309695,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 7189,
        "name": "Lazio vs Genoa",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 18:45:00",
        "result_info": "Genoa won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693161900,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13083633,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 43,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083631,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 43,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083632,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 102,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083634,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 102,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13084291,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 43,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13084292,
                "fixture_id": 18867324,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 102,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 18867327,
        "sport_id": 1,
        "league_id": 384,
        "season_id": 21818,
        "stage_id": 77464586,
        "group_id": null,
        "aggregate_id": null,
        "round_id": 309695,
        "state_id": 5,
        "venue_id": 134,
        "name": "Napoli vs Sassuolo",
        "starting_at": "2023-08-27 18:45:00",
        "result_info": "Napoli won after full-time.",
        "leg": "1/1",
        "details": null,
        "length": 90,
        "placeholder": false,
        "has_odds": true,
        "starting_at_timestamp": 1693161900,
        "scores": [
            {
                "id": 13083638,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 597,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083637,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 1525,
                "participant_id": 2714,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "CURRENT"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083635,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 2714,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13083636,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 1,
                "participant_id": 597,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 1,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "1ST_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13084295,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 2714,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 0,
                    "participant": "away"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            },
            {
                "id": 13084296,
                "fixture_id": 18867327,
                "type_id": 2,
                "participant_id": 597,
                "score": {
                    "goals": 2,
                    "participant": "home"
                },
                "description": "2ND_HALF"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Scores that are not showing for the right team(s).

[image: Example of scores that not display correctly]
[image: Example of scores that not display correctly 1]

Scores that are showing for the right team(s).

[image]

I tried to retrieve the data like `scores![i].score!.goals.toString()`

Comment: Do you have any output or console error?

Comment: @AshikulIslamSawan there is no error per say. The problem is the right scores are not showing for the correct teams. While other scores are showing for the correct teams. Please see the screenshots, I attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to 'solve' the problem. In the UI, I rearranged the home team in left side while the away team in the other side. By this, I am able to put the data(team scores, name, image) in the respective side. Also, I filtered the data from the JSon to a list.

[image]